# How can I read a file present inside resource folder in spring boot application, using IDE as well as Java -jar command?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

I have a file under resources directory as: resources/MOResponse/UploadResponse.json

Now when I use below code:

```
Resource resourceFetch = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/MOResponse/UploadResponse.json");
Reader reader = new FileReader(resourceFetch.getURL().getPath());
```

I can only able to access the file when I run the application from eclipse. But if I try to run the project via terminal using java -jar command gives error as "java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/user/Mintoak/mintoak/target/mintoak-mo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/MOResponse/UploadResponse.json (No such file or directory)".

Also, If I modify the code as below:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/MOResponse/UploadResponse.json");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream);
```

Then its working fine while running the application using java -jar command. But now when I run application from eclipse, resourceAsStream gives null.

Please provide the solution which work in both the scenario.

Comment: Resources are not files. You already had a `URL`. Just call `URL.openStream()` and you're done. No need to think about files at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `new FileReader`

Well, it's in the name: That reads files. Literally. Files only. A resource isn't one; it's some compressed bytes stuck in a jar file someplace (or at least, it could be).

Your second snippet is the right answer. If it returns `null` in eclipse, then your eclipse project is misconfigured. Specifically, the `resource` folder should be considered a source folder too.

Well, 'right answer' is a bit fluid here. You're using the right system but you're writing it in the wrong way. The right way to read resources is `ClassYouWriteThisCodeIn.class.getResourceAsStream`, not `getClass().getClassLoader()`. That second one breaks if you subclass, and also breaks in somewhat exotic scenarios, such as when your code is inside an agent run (because then classloader is `null` to indicate you're being loaded by the system booter). `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream` is equally simply and has strictly fewer caveats, which makes it strictly superior, which means it is the preferred style. Note that you need to prefix a `/` on your resource string if you do this (because without it, the resource string is relative to the package the class is in, which can be useful too).